# Best practice to save text description using 2 platform (react native and react)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, next.js

hope you doin well

I want to ask something, i have 2 platform using React Native and React (NextJS), and there's some form to save some data, and one of the data is `text description`, so here's the thing

when i input this:

```
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
```

and the output in my react native apps looks like:
[image: please see this image]

if you saw, there's some white space, this is good

but when we see react components, the text looks like this:
[image: please see this image]

if you saw it, there's no white space, this is not good

`but` at the same time, if i use markdown editor on web, i can't use it on mobile (not because i can't display markdown, but because of there's no way i use markdown editor on mobile),

is there any good use for this case? please helppp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) or  [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

p,
pre {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sollicitudin ullamcorper condimentum. Suspendisse augue nulla, interdum eget orci vehicula, molestie euismod est. Sed bibendum elit a ligula aliquet rhoncus. Morbi posuere elit cursus, scelerisque augue non, laoreet velit.

Nullam vitae massa blandit nulla aliquam condimentum. In luctus facilisis sodales. Vivamus condimentum molestie fermentum. Morbi et purus ligula. Praesent malesuada iaculis diam, vel blandit nulla efficitur quis. Vivamus molestie massa ligula, sed mattis nulla mattis vel. Etiam nec ligula aliquet, porta felis non, bibendum metus.

Aliquam bibendum auctor quam id ultrices. Ut ac suscipit tortor. Sed dictum ante ipsum, eu interdum purus rhoncus in.
<pre>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sollicitudin ullamcorper condimentum. Suspendisse augue nulla, interdum eget orci vehicula, molestie euismod est. Sed bibendum elit a ligula aliquet rhoncus. Morbi posuere elit cursus, scelerisque augue non, laoreet velit.

Nullam vitae massa blandit nulla aliquam condimentum. In luctus facilisis sodales. Vivamus condimentum molestie fermentum. Morbi et purus ligula. Praesent malesuada iaculis diam, vel blandit nulla efficitur quis. Vivamus molestie massa ligula, sed mattis nulla mattis vel. Etiam nec ligula aliquet, porta felis non, bibendum metus.

Aliquam bibendum auctor quam id ultrices. Ut ac suscipit tortor. Sed dictum ante ipsum, eu interdum purus rhoncus in.
<p>
```